# apt upgradeを取り消したい

Tags: apt

Ubuntu で `apt upgrade` をした後、もしシステムがおかしくなったらアップグレードを取り消せるのか気になりました。

`apt upgrade` をリバートするような、アンドゥ用のコマンドはありますか？

- 環境

  - Ubuntu 18.04.2
  - apt 1.6.10 (amd64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[この wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ListInstalledPackagesByDate) に書いてあるように、apt のログは `/var/log/apt/history.log`、`/var/log/apt/term.log`、`/var/log/dpkg.log` に残されています。

そこでたとえば `/var/log/dpkg.log` の内容を加工することでアップグレードされたパッケージを割り出し、ロールバックすることが可能です。

```sh
# 最近アップグレードされたファイルの一覧を出力し……
$ awk '$3 == "upgrade" {print $4"="$5}' /var/log/dpkg.log > rollback.txt

# ロールバックしたい行だけ残して……
$ nano rollback.txt  # 好きなエディタを使ってください

# 望んだ結果になるかチェックし……
$ xargs sudo apt-get --simulate install < rollback.txt

# 実際にロールバックする
$ xargs sudo apt-get install < rollback.txt
```

参考: [Can I rollback an apt-get upgrade if something goes wrong?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79050/211480)

---

ただし場合によっては、`E: Version '何とかかんとか' for '何とかかんとか' was not found` というエラーが出ます。`apt-cache` で調べると確かにありません。

```sh
$ xargs sudo apt-get --simulate install < rollback.txt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.96.24.32.8' for 'software-properties-common' was not found
$ apt-cache policy software-properties-common
software-properties-common:
  Installed: 0.96.24.32.9
  Candidate: 0.96.24.32.9
  Version table:
 *** 0.96.24.32.9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.96.24.32.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

この場合は[自分で .deb パッケージを作ってインストールする方法](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332116/211480)があるようです（未検証）。キャッシュに .deb パッケージが残っていれば[そこからもってくる方法](https://askubuntu.com/q/907506/644471)もあるようです（未検証）。

Comment: パッケージリストが長大になる場合を考慮して xargs を使うほうが良いかと思います。`xargs sudo apt install --simulate < rollback.txt` それから、依存するパッケージをインストールするかどうか尋ねられる場合があるので、実際にインストールする場合は `-y` オプションを付けると良いかと。`xargs sudo apt install -y < rollback.txt`

Comment: @metropolis さん、コメントありがとうございます。xargsを使ったバージョンに変えました。`-y`については個人的に自分でyesをしたいタチなので、敢えていれませんでした。